# Understanding Buck Converters

Tags: power-supply, power, amplifier, buck, converter

I need a little help designing a buck converter. Basically I want to generate a 5V output that will stay the same regardless of load resistance and that will exist when the input varies between 12 and 48 volts.
I understand the basic principle of the buck converter circuit but I do not understand how to make the PWM generator work. This circuit is supposed to be used for a charging circuit of a battery. Those being said, how am I supposed to power up the op amps needed for the PWM generator when this circuit is used for the power supply?
I attached an image with the circuit ( values not calculated yet ).

[image]

I found this IC online that is used with buck converters:
[image]
Source: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf?ts=1627292861171&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.it%252F

I want to do something like this but I don't really understand where do they take the voltage to power up the op amps, as it does not show.

Any help is welcome and thanks for every bit of help!

Comment: How it will charge the battery, what battery it is? Why do you need constant 5V for battery charging? How much current you need? Sounds like you want to design a buck converter chip replacement but you could just buy one chip and you have a buck converter, like in the picture, just add the necessary external components.

Comment: Why not just use a buck converter chip, or a pre-built module?

Comment: "regardless of load resistance" no buck converter can support any load, the inductor and switching frequency determine how much current can be switched and must be matched to a range of loads. Designing a buck takes some skill and use of buck equations

Comment: @Justme It is supposed to go into the charging circuit of a Li-Po battery as well as the rest of the circuitry.

Comment: And to answer your last question as well as @Hearth 's question, I need to design it, not to use a module. It's a requirement.

Comment: @VeNN00m I am not saying "buy a module". Modules are made around a buck controller chip or buck converter chip. Buy a chip like everyone else to make a module for yourself, or integrate it on your board.

Comment: @Justme Sorry for my misunderstanding. If it comes to it, I'll have to do that. But I'd still like to try and design one myself.

Comment: You will need several chapters of reading from an SMPS book if you want to design one yourself.

Comment: @VeNN00m People have been using buck converter/controller chips for about 40 years now to make buck power supplies, unless they are doing something exceptional. What could possibly be so exceptional to justify building your own, which requires at least one good book or university power electronics course about the subject of switch mode power supplies - assuming you know the basics. Just use a chip, follow the design procedure in the datasheet and you are done.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to design it" and "It's a requirement"? Is this an assignment for a course you are taking?

Comment: why are you required to produce something virtually guaranteed to be inferior to jelly bean parts? While i'm sure you can make something that spits out 5v, how clean will the output be? how effecient will it be under the whole range? It's not just about adjusting duty cycle by load, oh no, you need different edge timings, dead times, even different frequencies to get max efficiency between 12 and 48. How do you stabilize output before powering the load, or in an over-current situation? or when temp runs away? There's too many considerations to pound one out in an afternoon. or a month.

Comment: In response to everyone, it's more about learning than about making something really efficient. I am required to do so for a project, but I also want to learn the thinking process and design rules for auch a circuit.

Comment: Not a full answer to the whole question, but the onboard error amps and other control circuitry are often powered using a small linear regulator that's only enough to power that control circuitry, built into the chip.

Comment: So i ended up using the IC i found for the switching part. Thanks everyone for their feedback!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it was downvoted since it's an interesting (and relevant question)

It is *entirely correct* that these days you just have to choose a chip but sometimes you need to design something strange. In fact the hugely popular (here at least) HP/Agilent/Keysight 6033A power train is completely done with opamps and transistors.

The big interesting question is: how do I supply the opamps that run the power converter. This is usually called 'bias supply' (probably from the transistor base operating point). If you look at 99% of the integrated converter they usually contain a small LDO running at about 5V (7 to 10V is not unusual).

It works in this way: you turn on the main input, let's say 12 to 48V as in your example. You have a small *auxiliary* regulator (call it a zener with a pass transistor, a 7805, whatever) design to power just your regulation logic. You usually only need some 10mA or so so dissipation is usually manageable. With this power your regulator then start up the main supply.

This is the simplest case. Often you can do better: the main regulator then power ups a 'better' (often a secondary winding for flybacks or forwards) 5V regulator that takes over to the auxiliary LDO (often it's just a diode). So the bias supply is in fact only a startup supply and then the regulator 'self power' itself (being the 6033A a bench supply the auxiliary supply is something huge with about four different power rails and dedicated windings, but that's HP engineering :D)

Getting the bias supply from the mains (like for phone chargers) is slightly trickier since you can't usually put an LDO from the mains down to 5V (not that it isn't being done). Each regulator has its own strategy, often using the magnetizing current of the transformer to jump start the circuit.